# iPad virtual keyboard text entry: Way to type multiple capital letters without having to press SHIFT before each letter?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, caps-lock, settings

Let's say I'm typing a word in ALL-CAPS on the iPad.  Currently, the only way I know of how to do this is to press SHIFT before each of the letters.

Is there an alternative, like a sticky shift or Caps Lock function, where I can just go into a caps mode, type the letters I want as all caps, and then go back to normal text entry?  I've tried keeping my finger on the shift key as well while I type, but that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Works on iPhone as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tap the **Settings** app. and click on the **General** **menu** > the **Keyboard**. Then turn "Enable Caps Lock" on.

Now just ***double-tap the shift*** key to enable caps lock once using the keyboard.

you can see with image tutorial [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_enable_caps_lock_capslock_apple_ipad.html).

Answer (score 0):

Holding shift ought to work, also. Perhaps that relies on the caps lock option, but it works for me.